# Starting activity not working on some real devices

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a very strange problem with my Android application.
In short my application uses an receiver that listens for SMS from a certain number, if the phone receives an SMS from that number it should play some different tones and vibrate in a specific pattern, it should also start another activity.

This is working as intended on the avd emulator, but it does not work on all real android devices. Eg. it does not work, when it should start the activity it's just displaying a black screen, the application does not crash, just shows a totally black screen. On the other hand, on my friends phone the very same application works as it should, apart from that we have different vendors on the devices we also does not have the very same  android version, I have 2.3.3 and my friend has 2.3.5. I don't really think this is the problem but FYI.

I have connected my device to eclipse and did some debugging, but I can't find the problem. I don't know if it helps but below I have written some text from the Logcat, it's the activity ax.ha.it.smsalarm_jfbk/.AcknowledgeHandler that fails to start.
I also write down how I start the activity.

Start activity:

```
        if(enableAlarmAck == true && type.equals("primary")) {
        Intent ackIntent = new Intent(ctx,AcknowledgeHandler.class);
        ackIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ctx.startActivity(ackIntent);
    }
```

And the Logcat(sorry for the big log):

```
09-02 18:59:58.183: D/SMSDispatcher(224): New SMS Message Received
09-02 18:59:58.210: D/Gsm/SmsMessage(1151): SMS SC address: +358xxxxxxxxxx
09-02 18:59:58.210: D/Gsm/SmsMessage(1151): originatingAddress.address : +358xxxxxxxxxx
09-02 18:59:58.214: D/Gsm/SmsMessage(1151): SMS SC timestamp: 1346601684000
09-02 18:59:58.214: E/Gsm/SmsMessage(1151): hasUserDataHeader : false
09-02 18:59:58.222: D/Gsm/SmsMessage(1151): messageBody : Test
09-02 18:59:58.242: V/MmsSmsProvider(224): uri=content://mms-sms/threadID?recipient=xxxxxxxxxx
09-02 18:59:58.246: V/Telephony(224): getOrCreateThreadId cursor cnt: 1
09-02 18:59:58.394: D/SmsProvider(224): insert content://sms/1467 succeeded
09-02 18:59:58.406: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): setStreamVolumeIndex() stream 3, index 15
09-02 18:59:58.406: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 3, volume 0.668344, delay 0
09-02 18:59:58.406: I/FmReceiverService(231): BrdcstReceiver onReceive ACTION: android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION
09-02 18:59:58.406: I/FMRadioService(129): mReceiver: VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION
09-02 18:59:58.406: I/FMRadioService(129):    stream: 3
09-02 18:59:58.406: I/FMRadioService(129):    volume: 15
09-02 18:59:58.406: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): setStreamVolumeIndex() stream 10, index   15
09-02 18:59:58.406: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 10, volume 0.007499, delay 0
09-02 18:59:58.410: V/AudioHardwareALSA(84): setParameters(FMRadioVol=0.0074989409)
09-02 18:59:58.410: V/AudioHardwareALSA(84): FMRadioVol = 0.007499
09-02 18:59:58.410: I/AudioHardwareALSA(84): virtual android::status_t android::AudioHardwareALSA::setFmRadioVolume(float) : Volume = [0.007499]
09-02 18:59:58.410: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): setStreamVolumeIndex() stream 9, index 15
09-02 18:59:58.410: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 9, volume 1.000000, delay 0
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): Client(27) constructor
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): Create new client(27) from pid 1151, fd=39, offset=69, length=86475, audioSessionId=31
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): setDataSource fd=39, offset=69, length=86475
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): st_dev  = 45826
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): st_mode = 33188
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): st_uid  = 1000
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): st_gid  = 1000
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): st_size = 2418792
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): player type = 1
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84):  create PVPlayer
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/PlayerDriver(84): PVSuspensionState struct constructor
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/PVPlayer(84): PVPlayer constructor
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/PVPlayer(84): construct PlayerDriver
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/PlayerDriver(84): constructor
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/PlayerDriver(84): OpenCore hardware module not found
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/PlayerDriver(84): start player thread
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/PlayerDriver(84): startPlayerThread
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/PlayerDriver(84): InitializeForThread
09-02 18:59:58.414: V/PlayerDriver(84): OMX_MasterInit
09-02 18:59:58.417: V/PlayerDriver(84): OsclScheduler::Init
09-02 18:59:58.417: V/PlayerDriver(84): CreatePlayer
09-02 18:59:58.437: V/PlayerDriver(84): AddToScheduler
09-02 18:59:58.437: V/PlayerDriver(84): PendForExec
09-02 18:59:58.437: V/PlayerDriver(84): OsclActiveScheduler::Current
09-02 18:59:58.437: V/PlayerDriver(84): StartScheduler
09-02 18:59:58.437: V/PVPlayer(84): send PLAYER_SETUP
09-02 18:59:58.437: V/PlayerDriver(84): Send player code: 2
09-02 18:59:58.437: V/PlayerDriver(84): CommandCompleted
09-02 18:59:58.437: V/PlayerDriver(84): Completed command PLAYER_SETUP status=1
09-02 18:59:58.441: V/AudioSink(84): AudioOutput(31)
09-02 18:59:58.441: V/PVPlayer(84): setDataSource(39, 69, 86475)
09-02 18:59:58.441: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): [27] setAudioStreamType(3)
09-02 18:59:58.441: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): [27] prepareAsync
09-02 18:59:58.441: V/PVPlayer(84): prepareAsync
09-02 18:59:58.441: V/PVPlayer(84):   data source = sharedfd://40:69:86475
09-02 18:59:58.441: V/PlayerDriver(84): Send player code: 3
09-02 18:59:58.441: V/PlayerDriver(84): handleSetDataSource
09-02 18:59:58.441: V/PlayerDriver(84): handleSetDataSource- scanning for extension
09-02 18:59:58.441: D/(84): PVFile::GetFileName
09-02 18:59:58.445: V/PlayerDriver(84): CommandCompleted
09-02 18:59:58.445: V/PlayerDriver(84): Completed command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE status=1
09-02 18:59:58.445: V/PVPlayer(84): run_init s=0, cancelled=0
09-02 18:59:58.445: V/PlayerDriver(84): Send player code: 6
09-02 18:59:58.445: V/PlayerDriver(84): release string is 2.3.3 len 5
09-02 18:59:58.449: V/PlayerDriver(84): CommandCompleted
09-02 18:59:58.449: V/PlayerDriver(84): Completed command PLAYER_INIT status=1
09-02 18:59:58.449: V/PVPlayer(84): run_set_video_surface s=0, cancelled=0
09-02 18:59:58.449: V/PVPlayer(84): run_set_audio_output s=0, cancelled=0
09-02 18:59:58.449: V/PlayerDriver(84): Send player code: 5
09-02 18:59:58.449: V/PlayerDriver(84): Create realtime output 
09-02 18:59:58.449: V/PlayerDriver(84): CommandCompleted
09-02 18:59:58.449: V/PlayerDriver(84): Completed command PLAYER_SET_AUDIO_SINK  status=1
09-02 18:59:58.449: V/PVPlayer(84): run_prepare s=0, cancelled=0
09-02 18:59:58.449: V/PlayerDriver(84): Send player code: 7
09-02 18:59:58.449: V/PlayerDriver(84): disable natpkt - 0
09-02 18:59:58.460: V/PlayerDriver(84): HandleInformationalEvent: 44
09-02 18:59:58.460: V/PlayerDriver(84): HandleInformationalEvent: type=44 UNHANDLED
09-02 18:59:58.460: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): [27] notify (0x3f680, 200, 1, 44)
09-02 18:59:58.460: W/MediaPlayer(1151): info/warning (1, 44)
09-02 18:59:58.460: V/PlayerDriver(84): CommandCompleted
09-02 18:59:58.460: V/PlayerDriver(84): Completed command PLAYER_PREPARE status=1
09-02 18:59:58.460: V/PlayerDriver(84): PLAYER_PREPARE complete mDownloadContextData=0x0, mDataReadyReceived=0
09-02 18:59:58.460: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): [27] notify (0x3f680, 1, 0, 0)
09-02 18:59:58.460: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): [27] setVolume(0.000000, 0.000000)
09-02 18:59:58.460: V/AudioSink(84): setVolume(0.000000, 0.000000)
09-02 18:59:58.464: V/PVPlayer(84): check_for_live_streaming s=0, cancelled=0
09-02 18:59:58.472: V/AudioSink(84): open(44100, 2, 1, 4, 31)
09-02 18:59:58.472: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): getDeviceForStrategy() from cache strategy 0, device 2
09-02 18:59:58.472: V/AudioPolicyManager(84): getOutput() stream 3, samplingRate 0, format 0, channels c, flags 0
09-02 18:59:58.472: V/AudioSink(84): setVolume
09-02 18:59:58.472: V/PlayerDriver(84): HandleInformationalEvent: 41
09-02 18:59:58.472: V/PlayerDriver(84): .... with duration = 5146 ms
09-02 18:59:58.484: I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=ax.ha.it.smsalarm_jfbk/.AcknowledgeHandler } from pid 1151 //<--------The activity that fails to start
09-02 18:59:58.484: W/ActivityManager(129): Trying to launch ax.ha.it.smsalarm_jfbk/.AcknowledgeHandler
09-02 18:59:58.496: D/SMSDispatcher(224): BroadcastReceiver - mResultReceiver 
09-02 18:59:58.496: D/SMSDispatcher(224): GcfMode : 
09-02 18:59:58.496: E/SMSDispatcher(224): intent.getAction() : android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
09-02 18:59:58.496: D/SMSDispatcher(224): mResultReceiver : success = true
09-02 18:59:58.500: I/MediaPlayer(1151): Info (1,44)
09-02 18:59:58.562: I/Launcher(234): onResume(). mIsNewIntent : false
09-02 18:59:58.566: E/(234): onResume() check 0
09-02 18:59:58.566: V/ProgramMonitor(234): Binding::bindTaskManagerService() com.sec.android.widgetapp.programmonitorwidget.ProgramMonitorWidgetActivity$1@4056e350 com.sec.android.app.controlpanel.service.ITaskManagerService$Stub$Proxy@4063cef0
09-02 18:59:58.566: E/(234): onResume() check 1
09-02 18:59:58.566: E/Launcher(234): setWindowOpaque()
09-02 18:59:58.589: E/(234): onResume() check 2, mRestoring : false
09-02 18:59:58.589: E/(234): onResume() check 3
09-02 18:59:58.589: E/(234): onResume() check 4
09-02 18:59:58.589: E/(234): onResume() check 5
09-02 18:59:58.593: I/Launcher(234): onResume() ended
09-02 18:59:58.593: I/Launcher(234): onPause()
09-02 18:59:59.148: E/DataRouter(82): [*] Received suspend/ resume event but DUN is not up so neglect
```

AcknowledgeHandler.onCreate:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ack);

    //Shared preferences
    final SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(SmsAlarm.SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Get full message as string
    String fullMessage = sharedPref.getString(SmsAlarm.FULL_MESSAGE_KEY, "");

    //Get acknowledge number
    final String ackNumber = sharedPref.getString(SmsAlarm.ACK_NUMBER, "");

    TextView messageTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fullAlarmMessage);

    //Set larm text message to ui
    messageTextView.setText(fullMessage);

    //Find buttons and set the to button variables
    Button abortButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.abortAlarm);
    Button ackButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.acknowledgeAlarm);

    //Create objects that acts as listeners to the buttons
    abortButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    //Create objects that acts as listeners to the buttons
    ackButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Check if user has given any number to call, else show toast
            if(!ackNumber.equals("")) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ackNumber));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }   else {
                Toast.makeText(AcknowledgeHandler.this, R.string.cannotAck, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });      
}
```

Comment: According to code and logcat - the launching Intent is fine. You seem to have problem when creating this new Activity. Can you please paste a code of it, or at least onCreate/Start/Resume methods? Are you making heavy operations in onCreate?

Comment: Thx, for fast reply!
I updated my question with the activitys onCreate method. The other method the class contains is the onPause and the only thing that happens there is that it calls for super.onPause

Comment: That's strange, I see no problems in your onCreate(). Can I ask you also to check, if this activity contains any static/non-static initializer blocks? 
Also, can you please attach more LogCat logs? At least + second after "Trying to launch ax.ha.it.smsalarm_jfbk/.AcknowledgeHandler"?

Comment: remove everything in your activity code! Then start adding small stuff and check where it crashes.

Comment: I've found the bug!
The code works perfectly as long as the screen is "wake", but when the screen fades down and turns off the application fails to start the activity! Do you have any idea how to fix this issue, the activity should wake up the screen and start.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a forum.  Please use comments and [edit]s to respond to users questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following to turn the screen on and show your activity :

```
private android.view.Window window;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /**** Turn the screen on and show your activity ****/
    window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    window.addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.setContentView(R.layout.ack);
    /***************************************************/

    // setContentView(R.layout.ack);  // This is no longer needed

    /**** Rest of your code as it is ****/

    /*  ---------------------------- ****/

    /************************************/
}
```

But keep in mind that you are specifically only "waking the device and turning the screen on". You are not "unlocking" the device. When you press back key, you will see the lock screen. Essentially, your activity will turn on the screen and be displayed over the lock screen.

Hope this helps :)